# How to evaluate performance of Co-occurrence matrix

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I am learning the application of co-occurrence matrix as an alternative to Word2Vec. This [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/73e6/351a8fb61afc810a8bb3feaa44c41e5c5d7b.pdf) talks about how to improve the performance of co-occurrence matrix word embedding, and shows us the tables and graphs to visualize the improved performance of his model.

But I don't understand how the evaluation is done. His evaluation methods are explained in page 10 and 11. Can anyone explain how the values for Table 8, Table 9 and Figure 2 in this paper are obtained?

Comment: The caption of table 8 tells you exactly what those numbers are. What else are your trying to figure out?

Comment: @JosepValls Ive read the caption multiple times and the corresponding descriptions for WS- scoring methods, it still doesn't make sense to me.